# weights in a mixture Gaussian model

Tags: normal-distribution, mixture-distribution, weights

If the variance of a random variable is proportional to 
its mean, then what is the best way of making a mixture
distribution that will faithfully reconstruct a data
set coming from a mixture model.

For e.g. say I have a data set containing say N values of (x_i,sigma_i), and say x's are clustered at a few values (one can plot a histogram of x to
actually see this). Now if I want an approximate probability
distribution function in x, I can assume that each x_i
comes from a Normal distribution N(x_i,sigma_i), and then
add up all the Gaussians, hence getting a Gaussian mixture
model with equal weights. But the downside is that because
the variance is proportional to the mean, all the samples
with higher x values will have a lower contribution to the
sum, and the result may become biased and not reconstruct
the distribution of the data faithfully. For e.g it may not 
show peaks because of clustering at higher x values.

how can one get around this problem? is there a systematic
way to do this..

thanks

Comment: Do the underlying Gaussians have to have equal variances?

Comment: well they don't have equal variances. The std deviations are sigma_i's. So if there are N such Gaussians there are N different sigma_i's.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at Extreme Deconvolution by Bovy et al. (http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/10-AOAS439). It allows you to fit a GMM where each datum can have an arbitrary covariance matrix. The connection between mean and variance you have in your data is a special case of that situation.